# Bezier Tube - How to Fill the Ends?

Tags: bezier-curves

Would like to fill the end of this Bezier Tube with the same radius as the sides, not a flat piece. How is this done?

The OP may make further edits

I would like the end cap to have a rounded over look and not be flat like the first example or hollow like the 2nd.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean just fill in the end? Put a tick in Fill Cap - see first picture.

Or do you want the tube like effect in the next picture?  Add a Solidify Modifier and change Thickness to what you want.

[image]

[image]